# Is it possible to lock pdf with blank password?

Tags: command-line, password, pdf

I want to know if there is possibility to lock any PDF version 1.7 file with blank password using only command line approach ?

If not, then are there any GUI approaches to do the same.

Conversely, I would also like to know if there is way to supply empty password to unlock the PDF as well? Because I tried various online sites, browser based unlock, qpdf etc. But they don't provide functionality to support blank password as input.

Or unlocking/locking pdf doesn't support blank password?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to lock pdf with blank password?

[qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) and it is available from the [software center](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qpdf)

Example:

```
qpdf in.pdf out.pdf --decrypt --password=''
```